# How come when I paste this in vim, I get syntax errors?

Tags: python

```
def latlong_distance(origin, destination):
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371
    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c
    return d * 1000
```

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /tools.py on line 65, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: what does this have to do with vim?

Comment: It's probably a spacing issue (\xc2 is a space character), try and reindent using only spaces, nothing else. You can also put `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes that's right rafe, thanks.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then so we can get this resolved :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably a spacing issue (\xc2 is a space character), try and reindent using only spaces, nothing else. You can also put `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I modified that code a little:

```
dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
```

should split to two lines like this:

```
dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
```

I tried that, and there's no exception raised. Can you attached that file here?